# How can I list all symbols used in a call?

Tags: r, metaprogramming

I would like to list all symbols or names used in a call.

I found the following way but surely there is a more idiomatic or efficient approach ?

```r
expr <- quote(a + b * (a / b))
expr <- as.list(expr)
while(!identical(expr, (expr <- unlist(lapply(expr,as.list))))){}
unique(expr)
#> [[1]]
#> `+`
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> a
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> `*`
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> b
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> `(`
#> 
#> [[6]]
#> `/`
```

<sup>Created on 2019-08-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `all.names` to get *all symbols used in a call*:

```
expr <- quote(a + b * (a / b))
unique(all.names(expr))
#[1] "+" "a" "*" "b" "(" "/"
```